# Select distinct values from query excluding sorting-purpose column

Tags: mysql, sorting, distinct

#### Description:

I want to select my site content's categories. Most of them will be created by users so I will ve to deal with problem of many categories in table. I want to respect some kind content's trends on my site. My solution is:

- Select all categories from past 2 days and sort it by number of appearances (ascending),
- Union query (distinct)
- Select all categories from date < past 2 days and sort it like above.

Thanks to it I ve all most popular categories from small amount of time + most popular categories in global scope.

#### Query:

```
(SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS number FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND NOW() GROUP BY category)
UNION  
(SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS number FROM data WHERE date < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) GROUP BY category)
ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 50
```

#### Output:

```
+----------+--------+
| category | number |
+----------+--------+
|        2 |      3 |
|        4 |      3 |
|        6 |      3 |
|        5 |      2 |
|        1 |      2 |
|        2 |      1 |
+----------+--------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note there is duplicated content in category (id 2), UNION DISTINCT (default) is not excluding this because it compares rows from both columns, so:

```
+----------+--------+
| category | number |
+----------+--------+
|        2 |      3 | //is not equal to
|        2 |      1 | //below values
+----------+--------+
//wont be excluded
```

#### Problem to slove:

I need to select **distinct values** from only **category column**.

*(**number** is only for sorting purposes and used only in this query)*

Comment: Which of the numbers would you like to use? 3 or 1?

Comment: Column number only sort me the output. Simpler I want to split those two records into one, take it like theres no number column and only category - I dont want to appear twice category lets say "Video". To reach it I need to ve only one id with value 2.

Comment: Also I may suggest if there is any possibility to count rows from each select statement without adding them as alias column UNION should exclude duplicates properly, but I dont know how to make it unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should be the query that you need:

```
SELECT category
FROM (
  SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM data WHERE date BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND NOW()
  GROUP BY category
  UNION ALL
  SELECT category, COUNT(*) AS number
  FROM data WHERE date < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 DAY)
  GROUP BY category
  ORDER BY number DESC
) s
GROUP BY category
ORDER BY MAX(number) DESC
LIMIT 50
```

I removed brackets () around your two queries that make your union query because the ORDER BY of your UNION query will be applied to both. I also used UNION ALL instead of UNION because categories are grouped again in the outer query, i would try both UNION/UNION ALL to see which one is faster.

Then I'm grouping again, by category, and ordering by the MAX(number) of your category, and keeping only the first 50 rows.

Comment: Output 6,2,4,1,5 without duplicated values (category id's). Compare to output from question number of occurences 3,3,3,2,2. Works properly - marked as best anserw, thanks.